# How to check if a value exists in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to check if a token is unique before I use the save function, because I cannot create one from within.

I have tried to use the count, find and findOne functions, without any success...

```
exports.create_client = function(req, res){
    token = crypto.randomBytes(8).toString('hex') + '-' + crypto.randomBytes(8).toString('hex') + '-' + crypto.randomBytes(8).toString('hex')
    var client = new Client({
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
        pin_code: pincode_generator(6),
        token: token
    });
    client.save(function(err, userClient){
        if (err){
            if(err.errors.phone_number)
                res.status(400).send('Phone number is in use.');
            if(err.errors.token)
                res.status(400).send('Token is in use.');
        } else {
            res.status(201).send('User created successfully!')
        }
    });
};
```

Because of that the token is created in the server side it's the server's responsibility to give a unique token, and to prevent the error.

Comment: Are you using mongoose? Can you please share the `Client` model file?

Answer (score 3):

Before saving your data to Mongodb 
you should while defining your schema with mongoose 
set  `unique: true` to the  fields that you want to be saved as unique

```
 var clientSchema = new Schema({
   first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    phone_number: {type: String , unique : true }
    pin_code: String,
    token: {type: String , unique : true }
```

});

and you should handle errors

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved my issue by making an function object for the save function and call it from within it for saving again when I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that this value is unique in the DB as shown by rebai previously

```
client.save((err) => {
  if (err) {
    if (err.name === "MongoError" && err.code === 11000) {
      if (err.keyPattern. phone_number) {
        return res.status(422).send({
          success: false,
          error: "phone_number is already used" });
      }
    }
    return res.status(422).send(err);
  }
});
```